# Problem on Triangles and Circles

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I was solving this question, and I'm hitting a wall.

> The circle $ω$ touches the circle $Ω$ internally at $E$. The centre $A$ of $Ω$ is outside $ω$. Let $BD$ be a diameter of $Ω$ which is also tangent to $ω$. Assume $ED >EB$. Let $ED$ intersect $ω$ at $F$. If $DF=2EF$, what is the magnitude of $EDB$ in degrees?

This is the diagram I made: 
[image: Made with sketchometry]

I know that $\angle{BED}=90°$, so $DE^2+BE^2=4AD^2$. I think that I could construct a line from $F$, cutting $BD$ at $G$, so that $BE||FH$, and then using similarity, but I'm unsure.

Can anyone help?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Uhh... It's obvious from the diagram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first observation to make is that $$\triangle ECF \sim \triangle EAD,$$ because there is an obvious homothety with center $E$ that maps the circle $\omega$ to $\Omega$; moreover, since $AD = AE$ and $CF = CE$ are radii of $\Omega$ and $\omega$ respectively, the aforementioned triangles are isosceles.  Since $DF = 2EF$, then $AC = 2EC = 2r$, where $r$ is the radius of $\omega$.  Consequently, if $G$ is the point of tangency of $\omega$ to diameter $BD$, $\triangle CGA$ is right with $AC = 2r$ and $GC = r$.  Hence $$\angle CAG = 2 \angle EDB = 30^\circ,$$ and $\angle EDB = 15^\circ$.

Comment: What makes $\angle{ECF}=\angle{EAD}$? $ACE$ is a straight line, but how could $CF||AD$?

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo If the homothety argument is not used, then you can also argue that since $AD = AE$ and $CF = CE$, $\triangle ECF$ and $\triangle EAD$ are isosceles; therefore $$\angle ADE = \angle AED = \angle CEF = \angle CFE.$$